# What is the way to access object that is outside of #each in meteor template

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

I am new to Meteor and got stuck here.

```
<h1>{{otherObj.category}}</h1>
{{#each partners}}
  <p>{{name}} - {{otherObj.category}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

In this template snippet, otherObj is the object that i want to access in the loop. So this outputs

```
<h1>football</h1>
<p>Name1 - </p>
<p>Name2 - </p>
```

Further investigation revealed that OtherObj inside the loop is 'undefined'
Any idea, how can i access it inside the loop ?

Answer (score 5):

You need access to parent properties of each loop.

Use `../` like this :

```
<h1>{{otherObj.category}}</h1>
{{#each partners}}
  <p>{{name}} - {{../otherObj.category}}</p>
{{/each}}
```